# AWS S3 Download Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, price

I'm currently using AWS S3 and S3 glacier storage service through HyperBackup and Glacier Backup in NAS.

While using, I've got a few questions related to the pricing.
When downloading the files in the storage, which price will be applied?
Would that be "Get object (request)" or "Data Transfer"?

I've read this documentation about AWS (Downloading an object: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/download-objects.html). According to document, it seems like I can download objects through GET request, but it also says data transfer fees will be applied. I'm quite confused in this part since request and data transfer have quite different pricing range.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Plug some numbers into their calculator and it will give you your costs - https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html - basically you buy your GET requests in blocks, and pay transfer fees for the amount of data your GET requests return

Comment: Thank you for your advise, MisterSmith. I actually have already used Price estimator, but I'm still not sure if downloading files in buckets has fallen into the category of "Data Transfer" or "GET requests".

Comment: AWS bill you at a very granular level. So it falls into both - any request type (inc GET) that returns a response would result in data transfer.  A very simplistic example would be if you download a 2KB file 10 times - you make 10 GET requests and transfer 20KB of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data Transfer** will apply for *any* data that moves from the AWS Cloud to the Internet, regardless of whether it comes from S3, Glacier, EC2, etc.

The service-specific pricing will also apply for the functionality you are using.

Please note that there is a difference between the ['old' Amazon Glacier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/amazon-glacier-getting-started.html) (which uses Vaults) and the ['Glacier' storage classes](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/) used in Amazon S3 (which uses standard S3 but stores the data differently and at a different price).